# how to sort dictionary by value and store the sorted dictionary in same dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

the task is to sort the given dictionary by value in descending order

```
   d={2:1,8:4,5:6,7:4}
```

after solving,it has to be print like this

```
   d={5:6,7:4,8:4,2:1}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: it will get sorted but how to take sorted dictionary in same dictionary...instead of list